# Evaluate $ \lim _{x \to 0} \left[{\frac{x^2}{\sin x \tan x}} \right]$ where $[\cdot]$ denotes the greatest integer function.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate $$\lim _{x \to 0} \left[{\frac{x^2}{\sin x \tan x}} \right]$$ where $[\cdot]$ denotes the greatest integer function.

Can anyone give me a hint to proceed?

I know that $$\frac {\sin x}{x} < 1$$ for all $x \in (-\pi/2 ,\pi/2) \setminus \{0\}$ and $$\frac {\tan x}{x} > 1$$ for all $x \in (-\pi/2 ,\pi/2) \setminus \{0\}$. But will these two inequalities be helpful here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the inequalities $\cos x < 1-\frac {x^{2}} {2} + \frac {x^{4}} {24}$ and $\sin x > x -\frac {x^{3}} {6}$ you can check that $0\leq \frac {x^{2}} {\sin x \tan x} <1$ for all $x>0$ sufficiently small. Hence the integer part of this fraction is $0$ for such $x$. The function is even so the limit from both sides are $0$. To obtain the stated inequality for $\cos x$ note that $\frac {x^{2n+2}} {(2n+2)!} <\frac {x^{2n}} {(2n)!}$ if $0<x<1$. Group the terms of the Taylor series two by two and use this inequality. A similar argument works for $\sin x$.

Comment: But  How can this inequalities be true? How can you assume that the  sum of rest series of $cos x$ will be greater than $0$? @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: @cmi I have included a proof now.

Comment: My edit was for a typo.... \tan x for tan x

Comment: What would you do when $x \in (-1 , 0)$?@Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: $\frac {x^{2}} {\sin x \tan x}$ is an even function of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use the known expansions for $\sin x, \tan x$ for small $x$? Then have $$\frac{x^2}{\sin x \tan x} = \frac{x^2}{(x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \cdots)(x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \cdots)}.$$ The *rhs* only including terms up to $x^2$ can be written $$\frac{1}{(1 - x^2/6)(1 + x^2/3)}$$ and the denominator to order $x^2$ is $1 + x^2/6$ so that finally have $$\frac{x^2}{\sin x \tan x} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{x^2}{6} + \cdots} = 1 - x^2/6$$ and the integer part is 0.

Alternatively write the original expression as $$\frac{x^2 \cos x}{\sin^2 x}.$$

Comment: The second term in the series for $\tan x$ is $x^3/3,$ not $x^3/5.$

Comment: What do you do in the interval $(-1 , 0)$? @jim

Comment: To the proposer: The function is an EVEN function.

Comment: @cmi: $\dfrac{x^2}{\sin x\,\tan x}$ is  an even function.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet ooops, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Your $x^3/3$ versus $x^3/5$ slip makes no difference to the conclusion. You should be a physicist. They have a knack for making math errors that don't affect the result....... Even multiple errors that cancel each other out, leading to the right conclusion. Someone on this site asked for help about a paper by Einstein, where he (Einstein) did exactly that.